# return shared_ptr from function

Tags: c++, memory, smart-pointers

I have Class which returns std::shared_ptr aka Product_SPTR:

```
Product_SPTR Mill::Production(sf::Time time)
{
    if(m_isProducing)
    {
        if(elapsedTime.getElapsedTime()>m_manufacturingTime)
        {
            elapsedTime.restart();
            Flour_SPTR a(new Flour(5,1,ProductType::CONSTRUCTION),deleter<Flour>);
            return  a  ;

        }
    }

}
```

then i have `typedef std::vector<Product_SPTR> VectorProduct_SPTR`

and when I'm trying to add new Product_SPTR to vector i have `segmentation fault`

Here:

```
products.push_back(a->Production(gameTime.getElapsedTime()));
```

But when I do something like this:

```
products.push_back(new Flour(5,1,ProductType::CONSTRUCTION),deleter<Flour>);
```

problem  does not occur....

I have just started to use smart pointers so maybe i don't know how to use it ..

Comment: What is `deleter`? What does `Mill::Production` return when `m_isProducing` is false? Do you post complete code?

Comment: try to return by reference

Comment: There's no return statement for when either of the two conditions fail. That is a cause for undefined behavior.

Comment: No good question: Handle all warnings the compiler emits, or increase the warning level.

Comment: Yes it was stupid;)
return nullptr, and all problems go away..

Comment: @Decipher: Return a reference to what? A local variable that's already been destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a `return` statement when the conditions in both `if`s evaluate to `false`. It compiles, probably giving you compiler warnings. You should always work on the highest warning level and eliminate all warnings one by one, unless you understand a warning and its implications.

Additionaly, instead of writing

```
Flour_SPTR a(new Flour(5, 1, ProductType::CONSTRUCTION),deleter<Flour>);
return  a;
```

You probably should write

```
return Flour_SPTR(new Flour(5, 1, ProductType::CONSTRUCTION), deleter<Flour>);
```

Modern compilers shouldn't have any problems with optimizing out the redundant variable, but it's always good to help the compiler do it's job. If you could skip the deleter you could also write:

```
return std::make_shared<Flour>(5, 1, ProductType::CONSTRUCTION);
```